# WCF - Why would you want to create multiple endpoints for a service?

Tags: wcf

I am very new at WCF. I'm creating a prototype app to learn WCF. I have the following code to create a service host, which works fine:

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceMethods), new Uri("http://localhost:8888/MyService"));
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IB.Entities.ServiceInterfaces.ILocation), WcfConfiguration.GenerateBinding(Enumerations.WcfBindingType.HTTP), "");
```

My question is this. Since it appears you can add multiple endpoints for a service host, under what circumstances/situations would you want to do this? What would be the advantage(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say your WCF service hosts the BLL (business rules, data validation, database connections, etc) and you have windows clients written in C#, for those is best to make a endpoint that uses the TCP binding (faster serialization, works only between .NET apps), then you have a website written in php or java, in order for this site to call your service you'll need a HTTP endpoint (exposed by SOAP - like a basic Web service).

Answer (score 1):

1. You may want to publish Metadata for other devs to develop against, so adding a MEX end point.
2. You may want to support multiple protocols, e.g. NetTCP for .NET clients and WSHTTP for Java clients
3. You may also want to add a basicHTTP endpoint for legacy support.